# Async await hitting API so many times

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I use async and await in angular first time, and it worked for me, but I checked in network tab, then because of async and await, so many request was going for the same api. Did I something wrong ?

my ts file

```
private generateCommaSeperatedSettingLabel(tagDtoList: any[]): string {
    let label = '';
    return label;
  }

  async companydata(): Promise<any> {
    this.companyListData = await this.companyListService
      .getTagsCompanyList()
      .toPromise();
    this.settingLabel = this.generateCommaSeperatedSettingLabel(
      this.settingObject.tagDtoList
    );
    this.settingLabel = this.settingLabel.match(/.{1,19}(?:,|$)|[^,]+(?:,|$)/g);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.companydata();
  }
```

> my service file

```
populateCompanyListFromServer() {
    this.dataService.getTagsCompanyList().subscribe(data => {
      this.companyData = data;
    });
  }

  getTagsCompanyList() {
    const tagsUrl = '/Tag?objectTypeCode=SettingValue';
    const generatedUrl = this.common.generateCommonServiceUrl(tagsUrl);
    return this.http.get(generatedUrl)
      .pipe(
        map((response) => response)
      );
  }

  async getResponse(): Promise<any> {
    const res = await this.getTagsCompanyList().toPromise();
    return res;
  }
```

Before `async await`, I was facing problem that `populateCompanyListFromServer` method response was late, that's why in my TS file i was not able to get the data from my service in `ngOnInit()`. There for I implemented this
Instead of 1 request, it hitting 10-15 times don't know why. Is there any improvement I need? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, try to remove the `: Promise<any>` from companydata() function as it is not returning any promise, also try removing the `.pipe(map((response) => response));` from the method in service and use debugger at the start of companydata()  method to check how many times the method is called and why.

Comment: I did as just you said, but the problem is I putted debugger on line async companydata() , same function is calling multiple time.